# In Python, how do I get a variable via a string representation of the name of the variable?

Tags: python, string, class, self, hasattr

I'm using Python 2.7.

Take, for example, the following code:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def printVariable(self, s): # print variable named s
        if hasattr(self, s):
            print ...
```

What would I replace `...` with to print `self.'s'`. For example, if I called `printVariable('n')`, what would I put in place of `...` to print `n`?

Of course, `self.s` would not work because first of all there is no attribute `self.s`, but more importantly, that's printing a different variable, not the variable `self.'s'` I want to print the variable whose name is represented by the string `s` that is passed to the method.

I'm sorry about the inherently confusing nature of `self.s` and `self.'s'` and `s` in this question.

Comment: It's worth a note that this can often be a sign of a bigger design issue - often this means you want a data structure and not an attribute. What are you actually trying to achieve wiht this?

Comment: You should always try to keep data out of your variable names: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`hasattr(self,s)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr), is sufficient to your needs, then you want [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) :

```
if hasattr(self, s):
    print getattr(self, s)
```

In fact, you may be able to skip the `hasattr` altogether, depending upon your precise requirement. `getattr()` takes a default value to return if the attribute is missing:

```
print gettattr(self, s, 'No such attribute: '+s)
```

If you want to find variables outside of the current object (say, in local scope or global scope, or in another object), try one of these:

```
locals()[s]
globals()[s]
getattr(other_object, s)
```

Note: using `locals()`, `globals()`, and to a lesser extent, `hasattr(self,s)`, outside of a few limited cases, is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It almost very likely means that your design is flawed.

Comment: As a note, the `locals()` and `globals()` calls are extremely rarely a good idea.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after, but not totally sure...

```
print getattr(self, s)
```

You can also use it to specify what to return if it doesn't exist. See the [getattr docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
print getattr(self, s, 'default value')
```